# What kind of loop should I use in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

My boolean expression becomes false in the middle of my loop. What kind of loop should I use?
I keep reading through loop tutorials and each one mentions that a while loop cannot do this. I've tried combining a for loop and an if statement and that doesn't work either. Sorry for the simple question.

```
    }
     for(int k = 0;k < collb.length; k++){
        //what was used after first calculation
           grosssum += col4[k]*mix[k];
             one=sum1 - grosssum;


    }
   for(int n = 0;n < collb.length; n++)
    if(one < -need[n] && col4[n] >0){
   col5[n]=col4[n]-inc[n] + arrayspecificpounds[n];
    net += col5[n]*mix[n];
    sum = sum1-net;
 }   //net is the sum of what was used * mix
     //sum1 is what we started with
   else{
     if(one > need[n] && col4[n] >0){
    col5[n]=col4[n]-inc[n] + arrayspecificpounds[n];
    net += col5[n]*mix[n];
    sum = sum1-net;

    }
    else col5[n] = col4[n] +  arrayspecificpounds[n];
    sum = sum1 - net;
   }
   for(int p = 0;p< collb.length; p++){
       if(sum < -need[p] && col5[p] >0){
           col6[p]=col5[p]-inc[p] + arrayspecificpounds[p];
       net2 += col6[p]*mix[p];
       sum2 = sum1 - net2;
       }
     else{
           if(sum > need[p] && col5[p] >0){
               col6[p]=col5[p]+inc[p] + arrayspecificpounds[p];
      net2 += col6[p]*mix[p];
    sum2 = sum1 - net2;
           }
    else col6[p] = col5[p] + arrayspecificpounds[p];
    net2 += col6[p]*mix[p];
    sum2 = sum1 - net2;
   }
    }


        for(int q =0;q< collb.length; q++){
           if(sum2 < -need[q] && col6[q] >0){
               colr[q]=col6[q] - inc[q] +arrayspecificpounds[q];
           }
             else{
               if(sum2 > need[q] && col6[q]>0){
                   colr[q]=col6[q] +inc[q] + arrayspecificpounds[q];
               }
       else colr[q] = col6[q] + arrayspecificpounds[q];
           }
```

In this example sum2's value changes as array col6 is incremented but in the middle of the array the inequalities change. How would I implement a break to stop once sum2 changes?

Comment: First of all, show us what you tried.  Secondly, you're going to have to provide more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: it all depends. they both serve a purpose.

Comment: You can make the question more targeted by showing your code and perhaps explaining what you've discovered so far from your own research. The best questions here are the ones that demonstrate that you've put some effort into the topic, and something about the way you've worded this tells me you legitimately have a lot more you could contribute to make this a possibly great question. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for not adding my code, I edited it in.

Comment: Eric, I don't see where sum2 is being changed in your code? Also, for readability's sake, I strongly recommend you put curly braces around all your branches. You're less likely to trip someone up and make one of us read into the code wrong if it meets generally-accepted standards. While that may save people like me from embarrassment, it also benefits you by getting you the best possible answers.

Comment: jmort, I'm sorry I don't know what my branches are that need curly braces? I'm still trying to get my head around the standards, I'll try harder though! sum2 is determined before my loop starts, I edited it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how you can stop a while loop when a boolean value you're monitoring changes it's value from false to true:

```
boolean done = false;
int count = 0;

// while not done, continue looping
while(!done) {
    // do stuff
    count++;
    if(count > 7) {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

The same technique can actually be used inside a for loop as well:

```
boolean done = false;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000 && !done; i++) {
    // do stuff

    if(i > 7) {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

This is a bit unorthodox, but it demonstrates how the 2nd parameter in your for loop can be used to monitor a boolean condition that may or may not be related to the actual value of the int i value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a "break" to exit any loop when your condition is false

Comment: You should show an example so it's more clear how this would work.